# API Token alternative for inside request header

Tags: joomla-api

So the `X-Joomla-Token` with the API Key is added to the Request Header upon starting a request.
I have a partner that needs to access the API but is due to his infrastructure not able to add the Token to the Header.

Is it possible to add the Token to the query params like this:

```
https://www.mysite.com/api/index.php/v1/app/service?a=1&X-Joomla-Token=497562347562347562394756475623475634890756
```

I tested that with Postman, but it seems Joomla is not capable of processing that because i get an 401.

Answer (score 0):

Sending sensitive data as query parameter is extremely insecure. Token plugin does not and will not support this. If you really need this, you have to write your own API authentication plugin. The principle is the same as standard [authentication plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla), except it belongs to `api-authentication` group.

Comment: It's not sensitive, as the API access delivers only public information and is limited to a registered user group with limited rights.
I have tried to use the basic authentication plugin for api authentication, but every access gets redirected to standard url and fails. Will probably open a separate question for it.